# Get all possible entries SQL Join

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

Given the following product and substitution tables, how can I get an output with all possibilities?

Product Table

```
> Category | Year | Product Code
> :--------|------|-------------
> Animals  | 1998 | A0001
> Sports   | 2001 | A0002
```

Substitution Table

```
> Product From | Product To
> :------------|------------
> A0001        | A0003
> A0002        | A0004
> A0003        | A0005
> A0004        | A0006
> A0006        | A0007
```

Product A0001 was replaced for A0003 and then A0003 replaced for A0005.

Product A0002 was replaced for A0004, A0004 for A0006 and then A0006 for A0007.

The desired output is:

```
> Category | Year | Product From | Product To
> :--------|------|--------------|-----------
> Animals  | 1998 | A0001        | A0003
> Animals  | 1998 | A0003        | A0005
> Sports   | 2001 | A0002        | A0004
> Sports   | 2001 | A0004        | A0006
> Sports   | 2001 | A0006        | A0007
```

I think COALESCE function may help me but I can't build the query.

Comment: You're trying to walk a graph. To get the first row you'd need one join, the second though needs *two* joins*.  `COALESCE` won't help here. You may be able to use a [recursive CTE ](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1520/recursive-queries-using-common-table-expressions-cte-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple join can't produce this result. You need to walk a transition graph to generate each query. You can do this with a recursive query using [a CTE](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1520/recursive-queries-using-common-table-expressions-cte-in-sql-server/)

Given these tables :

```
declare @product table ( Category nvarchar(30), Year int, ProductCode nvarchar(30))

insert into @product 
values
('Animals',1998 ,'A0001'),
('Sports'   ,2001,'A0002');

declare @substitusion table (ProductFrom nvarchar(30),ProductTo nvarchar(30));

insert into @substitusion 
values
('A0001','A0003'),
('A0002','A0004'),
('A0003','A0005'),
('A0004','A0006'),
('A0006','A0007');
```

This query will walk the transitions and generate the desired result :

```
with x as (
    --Create the initial result by joining Product and Substitution
    select Category,Year,ProductFrom,ProductTo
    from @product p inner join @substitusion s on p.ProductCode=s.ProductFrom
    union all
    --Join the *previous* result with the next Substitution
    select Category,Year,next.ProductFrom,next.ProductTo
    from x as previous 
    inner join @substitusion next on previous.ProductTo=next.ProductFrom
)
select * 
from x
order by Category
```

This produces :

```
Category    Year    ProductFrom ProductTo
Animals     1998    A0001       A0003
Animals     1998    A0003       A0005
Sports      2001    A0002       A0004
Sports      2001    A0004       A0006
Sports      2001    A0006       A0007
```

The first query generates the first results by joining `Product` and `Substitution`. The *next* query joins any previous results with the next substitution, by joining the previous ProductTo to the next ProductFrom